# multiple ports server not getting all transmissions

Tags: c, linux, sockets

I wrote a single threaded server in c under linux,
this server listens to multiple ports,the server supposed to get text messages,
I use this code to listen to the sockets:

```
while(1){
FD_ZERO(&socks);
for (i = 0 ; i < IndexConnctedSocket ; i++ )
    FD_SET(newSocketFds[i],&socks);

readsocks = select(highNewSocket + 1,&socks,(fd_set*) 0,
        (fd_set*) 0 ,&timeout);

    for (j = 0 ; j <= index ; j++ ){
        if ( FD_ISSET(newSocketFds[j],&socks) != 0 ){
            bzero(buffer, 2048);
            n = read(newSocketFds[j], buffer, 2048);
            if (n < 0)
                error("ERROR reading from socket");
            i = 0;

            n = write(newSocketFds[j], "I got your message  ",18);
            if (n < 0)
                error("ERROR writing to socket");
            }
}
```

but when i send messages to the server (via a client that connects to all the sockets) some of the messages are lost,and when i connect from different clients to the server this works perfectly.

Comment: Is this TCP or UDP? Also you'll have to set timeout at every iteration of the loop.

Comment: its TCP, I have set the timeout to tv_sec = 1 and tv_uses = 0

Comment: He was saying:  Linux modifies the timeout you pass to it, to "reflect the amount of time not slept".  You could use this to determine how long you waited.  But it also means you need to set the timeout *back* to 1.0 sec before you call again, or you'll eventually end up busy-waiting.

Answer (score 0):

TCP does not have messages, so multiple "messages" can be obtained in one read().
Try checking the result (n) of your read() call.
You could check the buffer with

```
printf("read(%d): %*.*s\n", n, n, n , buffer);
```